# How to set acl on all parents, ancestors of a given path in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I need to ensure that a given user is able to read a given file in ansible. Of course I use an "acl" module (that uses setfacl) to give the user's read permission. That's easy. But I also need to make sure that the user can "execute" all directories up the tree of the file path. E.g.:

`read /var/lib/secured/directory/file
eXecute /var/lib/secured/directory
eXecute /var/lib/secured
eXecute /var/lib
eXecute /var
eXecute /`

Of course I'm writing a role, which does not know how many elements the path will have, so I need to have a dynamic loop in Ansible. But I don't know how to achieve this. 
I'll be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Hey mate, after 4 years am at the same requirement :)
Did you manage to create the role, couldn't find any on Galaxy.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to use ACLs?  If all you need to do is give execute permission to a user on a directory structure, my first thought it to use `chmod` - or in Ansible, the [file module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/file_module.html):

```
- file:
    path: /var/lib/secured/directory
    state: directory
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
    recurse: yes
```

or similar.

Comment: I need to use ACLs: The files are owned by someone else, highly secured and I can't give access to it to everyone. I need to give it selectively to some users/services. I'd be the most happy if I don't give X access to directories to everyone.

Comment: Can you put all relevant users in a group?

Comment: No, unfortunately. The file I want to give access to, is managed by someone/something else and I'm disallowed to change the owner/group of it. But please note, the question is not about ACLs, but about general thing: "how to apply a change up the tree?" It may be by ACLs, or changing group an owner and giving the group X permission. Your solution only gives X permission to the file, not directories on the path to the file.

Comment: No, what I put above uses the recursive abilities built into chmod to affect the entire tree.  Although that doesn't work for you, [the acl module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/acl_module.html) also has a `recursive` parameter available, which will work similarly and should be sufficient for you.